# .blend Files won't open but it asks me how i want to

Tags: blend-files

[image]

^ This is my problem. ^

At first, it may seem innocent, like I can just press "OK" in order to open blender, but that's not the case. Instead, when I press the "OK" button, the prompt pops up again. I'm trying to use Sims 4 Studio to make poses, but this prevents me from doing so. I appreciate any help!

*Thank you,*

*Fellby*

Comment: Did you try running blender then opening the file?

Answer (score 1):

You could open this file by going into Blender and clicking "file" And "open". You can then navigate to the file where you can click it and then "open". This should open the file.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I think in your case it can be because of the "%1" at the end of the data path. For me the fix was to click on more, scroll down and then find other application (don't know if that's how it's in English) then you find blender by selecting the path. You can try to change blenders path temporarily.

Why it opens Sims 4 studio is a total mystery to me and I cannot find a logical connection so my assumption is that it tries to open it with that data path but there migth be some confusion due to the "%1" that is there for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you should be able to select More apps, and scroll down to Find another app on this pc, and then browse to Blender.exe's location.  Checking the box to "Always use this app" will change the file type association.

As a last resort you can search for Default apps in the start menu.

[image: default apps]

Scroll down and select Choose default apps by file type.

[image]

Normally you'd have all the options from above here, but Microsoft have made this panel mostly useless.  However, if your Blender installation is listed you can choose that, or you can find Blender in the dreaded Microsoft Store.